# Finding transfer function based on Nyquist Diagram

Tags: control-theory

I have a **Nyquist Diagram** that looks like this:

[image]

The angular frequency at point **A** is $\sqrt 2$ rad/s. Now I would like to derive the transfer function based on the diagram. Now, I am given the choices of the open-loop transfer function as below:

\begin{align}
  (a)L(s) = \dfrac{s+k}{s(s^2+as+b)}\\
  (b)L(s) = \dfrac{k}{s(s^2+as+b)}\\
  (c)L(s) = \dfrac{s+k}{s^2+as+b}\\
  (d)L(s) = \dfrac{k}{s^2+as+b}
\end{align}

Currently, as far as I know, the place on the real-axis with the number 3 should have $\omega$ = 0. If I replace $L(s)$ with $L(j\omega)$ and put in $\omega$ with 0, then options (a) and (b) will not satisfy because the results of them will be infinity. However, I am not certain how to derive the full transfer function in a standard way and find k, a, b. I have tried to use (c) and (d) and replace $\omega$ with $\sqrt 2$, but it failed either.

This is how I did when trying to get the transfer function based on option (c) and (d):

\begin{equation}
  L(j\sqrt 2) = \dfrac{k}{(b-2)+ja\sqrt 2} * \dfrac{(b-2)-ja\sqrt 2}{(b-2)-ja\sqrt 2} = \dfrac{k[(b-2)-ja\sqrt 2]}{(b-2)^2 + 2a^2} = 0 - j\dfrac{3}{4}\sqrt 2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   L(j\sqrt 2) = \dfrac{k + j\sqrt 2}{(b-2)+ja\sqrt 2} *  \dfrac{(b-2)-ja\sqrt 2}{(b-2)-ja\sqrt 2} = \dfrac{[k + j\sqrt 2][(b-2)-ja\sqrt 2]}{(b-2)^2 + 2a^2} = \dfrac{k(b-2) + 2a - j(k-b+2)\sqrt 2}{(b-2)^2 + 2a^2} = 0 - j\dfrac{3}{4}\sqrt 2
\end{equation}

From option (d), it looks like k, a, and b should satisfy the following equations:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    k(b-2) + 2a = 0\\
    (b-2)^2 + 2a^2 = 4\\
    k-b = 1
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

With option (c), this seems not to make sense because I think **a** could not be an imaginary number in this case. As for option (d), the equation, there seems no value pairs meet at the same time..., What did I miss?

Please help me with this question. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You have correctly eliminated option (a) and (b). But have you also attempted to eliminate either option (c) or (d) as well? And can you also show your attempt at solving for the transfer function in case of option (d)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I have reviewed the options (c) and (d). Would you mind seeing if there is anything wrong with my calculation?

Comment: By equating two fractions with each other it is not required that each numerator and denominator are equal. Namely, when multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by the same coefficient it can still be the case that the two fractions are equal. Instead try to equate the two fractions directly to each other.

Comment: Also don't forget to use $L(0)=3$.

Comment: For option (d) you need $b-2=0$ not $k(b-2)+2a=0$.

Comment: Thank you for advices. I will check the equation one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With options (a) and (b),

$$
    \begin{align*}
        L_a(jω) & = \dfrac{jω + k}{jω(-ω^2 + jaω + b)}, L_b(jω) = \dfrac{k}{jω(-ω^2 + jaω + b)} \\
        L_a(j0) & = ∞, L_b(jω) = ∞ \\
    \end{align*}
$$

Therefore, options (a) and (b) do not correspond to the graph.

With option (c) and (d),
$$
    \begin{align*}
        L_c(jω) & = \dfrac{jω + k}{(b-ω^2) + jaω} * \dfrac{(b-ω^2) - jaω}{(b-ω^2) - jaω} = \dfrac{(jω + k)(b-ω^2-jaω)}{(b-ω^2)^2 + (aω)^2} \\
        L_d(jω) & = \dfrac{k}{(b-ω^2) + jaω} * \dfrac{(b-ω^2) - jaω}{(b-ω^2) - jaω} = \dfrac{k(b-ω^2-jaω)}{(b-ω^2)^2 + (aω)^2} \\
    \end{align*}
$$

With $ω = \sqrt 2, L_c(j\sqrt 2)$ has a real part, hence the possible solution is (d)

Based on option (d)
$$
    \begin{align*}
        L_d(jω) & = \dfrac{k}{(b-ω^2) + jaω} * \dfrac{(b-ω^2) - jaω}{(b-ω^2) - jaω} = \dfrac{k(b-ω^2-jaω)}{(b-ω^2)^2 + (aω)^2} \\
        L_d(j0) & = 3 = \dfrac{k}{b} \\
        L_d(j\sqrt 2) & = 0 - j\dfrac{3}{4}\sqrt 2 = \dfrac{k(b-2-ja\sqrt 2)}{(b-2)^2 + 2a^2}
    \end{align*}
$$

Therefore,

$$
    \begin{align*}
        \begin{cases}
            k = 3b \\
            b - 2 = 0 \\
            \dfrac{-jka\sqrt 2}{2a^2} = -j\dfrac{3}{4}\sqrt 2
        \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
$$

$$
    b = 2, k = 6, a = 4
$$